# Python - Add Date Stamp To Text File

Tags: python, datetime, text

In Python v2, is there a way to get a date/time stamp and put it into creating a new text file?

IE: When I want to create a new text file and write the contents of my program to it, it will create a new text file with the time/date in it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "When I want to create a new text file and write the contents of my program to it, it will create a new text file with the time/date in it": first "it" means "the file", second "it" means "my code" -- PLEASE edit your question to say explicitly whether the third "it" means "the file" or "the NAME of the file.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
import datetime

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_{fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

with open(timeStamped('myfile.txt'),'w') as outf:
    outf.write('data!')
```

Comment: +1 for using `'-'` as the time-element separator ... `':'` is not a valid character in a Windows file name or directory name.

Comment: Note that the `String.format()` method is not available for all versions of Python v2, and nor is the `with open` block, so if the example doesn't work then that might be the reason.

Answer (score 9):

This will prepend a timestamp to the front of the filename:

```
from datetime import datetime

# define a timestamp format you like
FORMAT = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
path = 'foo.txt'
data = 'data to be written to the file\n'
new_path = '%s_%s' % (datetime.now().strftime(FORMAT), path)
open(new_path, 'w').write(data)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import datetime

f=open("/home/rohitsai/Documents/acs.txt",'a')
f.write ("heloo"+'\t')
f.write(datetime.datetime.now().ctime())
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

this code will add helo as well as current date on same file. 'a' is for append mode, \t for tab space.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
open("file", "w").write(datetime.datetime.now().ctime())
open(datetime.datetime.now().ctime(), "w").write("foo")
```

Comment: That is writing the datetime into the text file, is there a way to add it to the name of the text file?

Answer (score 1):

I like just having the date in my file handles:

```
from datetime import date

def timeIzNow():
    '''
    returns current date as a string
    '''
    now = date.today()
    full = "-" + str(now.month) + "-" + str(now.day) + "-" + str(now.year)

    return full

fileN = "findGenes"

with open(fileN + timeIzNow() + ".txt", 'w') as f:
    #DO STUFF
```

Your new file name will  look like

```
findGenes-6-5-2013.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these answers are unnecessarily complicated if you just want to spit out a timestamp to a file and don't care about tweaking the format of said stamp

You can literally do it in one line:

```
f.write(datetime.now().__str__() + "\n")
```

Here I assume `f` is a file - so we print the string representation of `datetime.now()` and add a new line, because `write()` doesn't do that for you. (You probably already knew that though.)

Note: checked working with Python 3, I didn't test with Python 2, I'm not sure which version of the language spec you are using.

Comment: You need more context in this answer - It is required to use `datetime.datetime.now()` . If you just try `import datetime ; datetime.now()` you get `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'`.

Comment: @wesinat0r Try from datetime import datetime or datetime.datetime - something like that, you just need an additional level import from the module